# Loading the same view twice with different variables

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller

Using CodeIgniter framework I'm trying to load two views that are the same, but with different data variables.

The code:

**Controller**:

```
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('myview', $data_view, TRUE)

$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

**somewhere in `template.php` View before outputting `$content` variable**:

```
$this->load->view('custom_menu', array('select' => FALSE));
```

**in `myview.php` View**:

```
$this->load->view('custom_menu', array('select' => TRUE));
```

**The problem**: Both `custom_menu` views load with the same variable as in the last view loading, eg. `$select = TRUE`

I've already tried making the second custom_menu and that works well, but I want to understand why I can't have the same view with different variables.

Comment: I am curious as to what your custom_menu and template views look like. Are you able to provide a code examples.

Comment: Code examples are irrelevant here. Imagine an if ($select) <html> in custom_menu view. Template is just HTML template with <?php echo $content; ?>

Comment: Well what you think you are doing and what you are actually doing are two different things. You've explained what should happen but I cannot see from what you have shown as to why it's not happening. Bottom line is what you are expecting should work.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I have understood your layout from what you have provided.

This is my take on what you might have which works.

**Controller - main.php**

```
public function index() {
    $data_view['content'] = "<h3>This is content</h3>";
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('myview', $data_view, TRUE);
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

**View - template.php**

```
<h1>My Template</h1>
<?php
$this->load->view('custom_menu', array('select' => FALSE));
?>
<?= $content; ?>
```

**View - myview.php**

```
<?php
$this->load->view('custom_menu', array('select' => TRUE));
echo $content;
```

**View - custom_menu.php**

```
<?php if ($select):?>
<h2>Menu 1 - When Select is TRUE</h2>
<?php else: ?>
<h2>Menu 2  - When Select is FALSE</h2>
<?php endif;?>
```

Which results in the HTML Output ( from the browser ) of...

```
<h1>My Template</h1>
<h2>Menu 2  - When Select is FALSE</h2>
<h2>Menu 1 - When Select is TRUE</h2>
<h3>This is content</h3>
```

So it works just fine.

Is that what you are attempting to do?

Comment: Basically, yes. With the exception that in `myview.php` I don't output `$content`.
I agree that this is the expected output, that was my expectation also, but instead imagine that the output is `Menu 1 - When Select is TRUE` twice.

Comment: Well the above is tested, working code. If you copy and paste it, it will work. You would have to be setting the value to TRUE in both cases to get it twice. So what else is different between what I have and you have? Always best to go back to something simple to test this stuff out.

Comment: What I have is much more complex. I will stick to copying the same `custom_menu.php`. I just wanted to understand why this is happening. Thank you for your time & help :).